# Why is my "old" meta profile still available for viewing?

Tags: support, user-accounts, meta

Now some months ago there was technical glitch involving my profile which got like deleted and a new one created. The old profile on main is no longer there but why is my [meta profile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5783/benjalim)  still around? Can a moderator please delete it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for clarification: you want it deleted, not merged into your current account right?

(I think the problem happened because your technical glitch was solved *manually*, by someone going in and editing the database. It may be that they just never got around to doing also the Meta.Math account.)

If you want it merged, you should send an e-mail to `team@stackexchange.com` explaining the problem. If you want it just deleted, comment below and I'll delete it (fingers crossed that nothing bad happens to your current account in the process).

Comment: I don't think it is linked to my current account because there are different profile numbers. Please delete it.

Comment: @BenjaLim Moderators can't delete meta profiles alone, your account is in some inconsistent state due to the previous problems. This really needs an SE developer to fix.

Comment: I've cleaned it up, @BenjaLim. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks so much!